# Sed equivalent in a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, scripting, sh

I have a shell script (.sh) where I use the **sed** command to replace the last matching character in a file(I have placed the command below).

How should I replace the command to get the same functionality in a batch file (.bat) without adding any packages/plugins (To be compatible in windows 7 and later)?

```
sed -i '$ s/,/;/g' abc.java
```

Comment: Don't. Just install/use cygwin and move on...

Comment: Can I use the same command just by installing cygwin in windows?

Comment: Yes, that's the point.

Answer (score 5):

Windows batch scripting does not have any native tools that can conveniently do anything similar to sed.

You could probably use PowerShell with a simple script, or CSCRIPT with a small custom VBS or JScript script.

I would use [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. It does not require any non-native exe or com files.

Full documentation is available from the command line using `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged help.

Your simple task could be performed by JREPL using:

```
call jrepl "," ";" /inc -1 /f abc.java /o -
```

Comment: Should I install anything to my machine to use jrepl? My machine has windows 7

Comment: @PrakadeesshArunachalam - You just need to copy the code found at the link and paste it into a file named JREPL.BAT. The file must be saved as ASCII (not Unicode). It is most convenient if you put JREPL.BAT in a folder that is listed within your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `sed` in Windows, not without any plugin or add-on. If you need to use sed, you can install SED for Windows.